# Continuity in a connected but disjoint space

Tags: general-topology

1. Suppose that a space $X$ is the disjoint union of two subsets $P, M \subset X$.
2. Suppose further that both $P\subset X$ contains limit points of $M\subset X$ and $M\subset X$ contains limit points of $P\subset X$, so that $X$ is not separated although disjoint. See below$^1$
3. Finally, suppose that the spaces $P$ and $M$ are homeomorphic.

Is there a finer topology for $X$ than the minimal topology described below $^1$ that can be derived from a finer topology of $P$ and $M$ such that $X$ supports continuity? The Disjoint Union topology is not a solution since it requires that $P\subset X$ and $M\subset X$ be open sets of $X$. My attempts to put any finer topology on $X$ have been unsucessful.

$^1$ Let $X$ be the disjoint union of two sets $P$ and $M$ so that $X = P\cup M$ and $P\cap M = \emptyset$. Then let $P$ and $M$ each contain limit points of the other. This requires that both $P$ and $M$ be neither open nor closed. $X = P\cup M$ is then disjoint but not separated, and is clopen. Then let $A$ be the set of limit points of $M$ contained in $P$ and $B$ be the set of limit points of $P$ contained in $M$. It follows that Both $A$ and $B$ are neither open nor closed, but each is the closure of the other and $A\cup B$ is a closed set of $X$. This creates a minimal topology on $X$ in which $P\cup M$ is the whole space, P\A, M\B, and (P\A $\cup$ M\B) are the open sets.

Comment: What does it mean for a space $X$ to be continuous?

Comment: Continuity is a property of functions not spaces

Comment: the disjoint union is inherently disconnected, do you mean to say that X is a modification of the disjoint union?

Comment: If you say that $P$ contains limit points of $M$, then you are already assuming there is a topology on $X$

Comment: The real line is continuous (though I don't know what that means, but it ought to be), and let $P=\{[n,n+1):n$ is odd$\}$ and $M=\{[n,n+1):n$ is even$\}$. Then $P=M+1$ (and also $M=P+1$) so they are homeomorphic, disjoint, each odd integer $n$ is a point of $P$ and a limit point of $M$, and each even integer $n$ is a point of $M$ that is a limit point of $P$. This seems to relate to your question, but it is not clear what you are describing, and what you are asking. You cannot say that $P$ contains limit points of $M$, unless there is already a topology on $X$. Related example Sorgenfrey line

Comment: What you denote as the "disjoint union" is not that what one usually understands:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)

Comment: Apologies for not being more clear. I have edited and expanded the question.

Comment: What does "$X = P\cup M$ is then disjoint but not separated, and is clopen" mean?

Comment: It means that the sets P and M are disjoint, hence share no points in common, but they each contain limit points of the other, hence they are not separated. Since their union is the whole space of a topology, their union is clopen.